# The Instantaneous Frequencies from IMF Aren't Consistent with Its Spectrum

Tags: frequency-spectrum, hilbert-transform

I'm trying to find the instantaneous frequencies for one of the Intrinsic Mode Functions (IMFs) I extracted from the original signal using Hilbert-Huang Transform. So, I got the following spectrum for that IMF:

[image]

However, when I tried to get the instantaneous frequencies for this IMF, I got the following (I'm using this [library](http://pyhht.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apiref/pyhht.html#pyhht.emd.EmpiricalModeDecomposition.mean_and_amplitude)):

```
[x,_]=inst_freq(imfs[0])
x*fs
Out[17]: 
array([100., 200., 100., 100., 200., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100.,
       100., 200., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 200., 200.,
       100., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100.,
       200., 100., 200., 200., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 200.,
       200., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 200., 200., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 200.,
       100., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100., 200., 200., 200., 100.,
       100., 200., 200., 100., 100., 100., 100., 200., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 200., 200., 200., 100., 100., 200., 200., 200.,
       100., 100., 100., 100.])
```

From the instantaneous frequencies, one could imagine that the spectrum contains only the 100 and 200 Hz frequencies. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you think you can turn your comment into an answer and "self-accept" that answer? This will close this question gracefully and it will stop it from circulating the board as unanswered. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a major bug in this library. see http://github.com/jaidevd/pyhht/issues/43#issuecomment-398388106 I think it's better to use more robust libraries that are well-tested.